# KVM switch not detecting keyboard

Tags: keyboard, eeepc, kvm-switch

I've just plugged in a Belkin Flip KVM to handle switching between my desktop and my Eee PC 1000. The mouse and monitor switch fine, but the separate keyboard does not work when the KVM switches to the netbook. The keyboard integrated into the netbook works fine, and the separate keyboard works fine when the KVM switches to the desktop.

This model of KVM runs the keyboard and mouse through a single USB, I suspect this is what is confusing the Eee PC.

How can I get the Eee PC to detect and use the seperate keyboard?

Both machines are running Oneiric.

Comment: Have you tried using this KVM on another system, to isolate that it is an Ubuntu issue?

Comment: Did you use this KVM switch with the Eee PC before this?

Comment: Then what you can try is this link (once the forums are back up, they have a message saying they will be in a week or so) http://forum.eeeuser.com/viewtopic.php?pid=523369

Comment: @Seret Could you provide a little more information, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into)

Comment: what Flip switch.. there are 5 http://www.belkin.com/IWCatSectionView.process?Section_Id=206974

Comment: Depending on your knowledge level and skillset you may be able to adapt this to toggle the keyboard and not the mouse. http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/how-faq-forums/unreviewed-how-faq/458356-automatic-disabling-eee-pc-1000-touchpad.html or one of the other users may stumble onto this and write it for you - unfortunately I am fairly new to ubuntu and wouldn't be able to do that.. sorry.

Comment: We need to know exactly what your switch model is, please add to the question. Also test this situation: boot the eee pc with the switch on the eee pc position, does the kb work? Flip it between the desktop and the eee pc, what works then in this scenario? On the eee pc do you have one of those USB ports that have constant power on them? Can you try the switch on that port (if it exists)?

Comment: Please also add the output of `lsusb` with the switch connected, disconnected, with the switch activated to the eee pc, with the switch not activated to the eee pc.

Comment: Turns out it a stupid mistake, see my answer below.

Comment: **CLOSE**, as now resolved

Comment: Closed and upvoted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, firstly, thanks for your help everyone!

Secondly, the issue is resolved.

Somewhat embarrassing, but after scouring the internet and getting together a whole pile of info to post back here I took a minute to double-check the setup and found that I had accidentally swapped the plugs for keyboard and webcam. What an idiot!

For future reference the exact model of KVM is the Belkin Flip USB with audio, and it's now confirmed working perfectly with Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Thanks for adding this information instead of leaving the question abandoned. Can you click the green check box on your answer and mark it *answered*?

Answer (score 1):

this issue is a hardware specific ... Unfortunately your switch is not supported by the laptop.. read [here](http://wiki.eeeuser.com/hardware%3aeee_un_supported_devices#switches)

as was pointed out to me this is actually the supported list - and as pointed out by you that your device is not listed - don't know if that means anything.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the same KVM. Mine is a Belkin Flip, a desktop model.